# I got an error when I tried to run an application using room database with coroutine as everything in Dao and Entity is annotated properly

Tags: database, android-room, entity, kotlin-coroutines

error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
This is the error shown when I run my application as DAO and Entity is correctly annotated with @.

```
@Dao
interface NoteDAO {

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertNote (note: Note)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateNote(note: Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note: Note)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM NOTES ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllNotes() : LiveData<List<Note>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM NOTES WHERE noteTitle LIKE :query OR noteBody LIKE :query")
    fun searchNote(query: String?) : LiveData<List<Note>>
}
```